# R variable scope using gradient function

Tags: r, scope

I got error message argument is missing with no default when using the gradient function. It seems that variables are not passed to other functions. pi(1,3) works, but gradient(pi, 1,3) would result in error message "Error in s(p1, p2) : argument "p2" is missing, with no default" Can anyone help explain why this happens and how to fix it? Thanks. See code below

```
rm(list = ls())
n = 2000
# 1 for T, 2 for S, 0 for T, 1 for S
v1 = 8
v2 = 10
mc1 = 1
mc2 = 2
tc = 2 # travel cost

s = function(p1, p2) { # share for two markets
  u1 = function(x) v1- p1 - tc * x
  u2 = function(x) v2 - p2 - tc * (1 - x)
  udiff = function(x) u1(x) - u2(x) # x prefer 1, (1-x) prefer 2
  # previous if ensures a root in uniroot function
  xbar = ifelse(u1(0) < u2(0), 0, ifelse(u1(1) > u2(1), 1, 
                                           uniroot(udiff, interval = c(0, 1))$root))
  # in case utility negative
  x1 = ifelse(u1(0) < 0, 0, ifelse(u1(1) >= 0, 1, uniroot(u1, interval = c(0, 1))$root))
  x2 = ifelse(u2(1) < 0, 0, ifelse(u2(0) >= 0, 1, 1-uniroot(u2, interval = c(0, 1))$root))
  s = c(min(xbar, x1), min(1 - xbar, x2))
}


pi = function(p1, p2) {
  pi1 = (p1 - mc1) * s(p1, p2)[1]
  pi2 = (p2 - mc2) * s(p1, p2)[2]
  return(c(pi1, pi2))
}

g = function(p1, p2) diag(gradient(pi, p1,p2))

gradient(pi, 1,3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you type `?pracma::gradient`, you will see that

> Usage: gradient(F, h1 = 1, h2 = 1)

and

> F: vector of function values, or a matrix of values of a function of two variables.

In your case `pi` is just the name of function, rather than numeric input arguments for `gradient`.

---

I have no clue what is your exact objective for your `gradient` or `g` function. An example to make your code run might be something like below

```
g = function(p1, p2) diag(gradient(pi(p1,p2), p1,p2))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I am using rootSovle.gradient, and the documentation suggests f can be a function name. It has an example code SF <- gradient(f = logistic, x, times = 0:50), where logistic is a function they defined above.

Comment: @cadenHong Okey, maybe you'd better mention that package in your post. I had trouble in installing `rootSolver`, sorry that I cannot go into the error and debug